# onClick Shuffle button from database

Tags: javascript, php, html, button, shuffle

For example I have this sentence, 'I like to play the piano.' It it separated into 4 elements, which will be taken out from the database(myphpadmin). How can make it as in only when I press the shuffle button, then it will shuffle.

```
   <body>
   <?php
// Connect to database server
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die (mysql_error ());

// Select database
mysql_select_db("login") or die(mysql_error());

// Get data from the database depending on the value of the id in the URL
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM sentences WHERE id 
    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;";

//create an array with numbers 1-4
$order = array(1,2,3,4);

//shuffle them in random order
shuffle($order);

$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

// Loop the recordset $rs
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    // Write the data of the person
    //Display all the array values from 0-3 (array index starts from 0)
    echo "<dt>Sentence:</dt><dd>" . $row[$order[0]] . " " . $row[$order[1]] . " " .                       
    $row[$order[2]] . " " . $row[$order[3]] ."</dd>";

    }
// Close the database connection
mysql_close();
?>

   <button onClick="Shuffle()">Scramble</button>

    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd basically need to do this with [**jQuery**](http://www.jquery.com).

Harnessing [`jQuery.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) to run an ajax request to your seperate php script.
Basically you'd have a php script with your code set up like this:

Lets call it `sentence.php`.

```
<?php
// Connect to database server
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die (mysql_error ());

// Select database
mysql_select_db("login") or die(mysql_error());

// Get data from the database depending on the value of the id in the URL
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM sentences WHERE id 
    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;";

//create an array with numbers 1-4
$order = array(1,2,3,4);

//shuffle them in random order
shuffle($order);

$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

// Loop the recordset $rs
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    // Write the data of the person
    //Display all the array values from 0-3 (array index starts from 0)
    echo "<dt>Sentence:</dt><dd>" . $row[$order[0]] . " " . $row[$order[1]] . " " .                       
    $row[$order[2]] . " " . $row[$order[3]] ."</dd>";

    }
// Close the database connection
mysql_close();
?>
```

Now you'd have your html file, lets call that `index.html`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button id="showcontent">Scramble</button>
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

In your `script.js` you'd be running your jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on('click', '#showcontent', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.get("sentence.php", function(data) {
            $("div#content").html(data);
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: I have tried but the array are not appearing on the html page. There is only the shuffle button.

Comment: @user3678617 did you modify the script to link to your actual files?
check the web developer tools console and see if there are any errors there...

Comment: No error found and I had modify the script to link with the html file. But the senetence is not appearing accept the shuffle button.

Comment: @user3678617 look in your network tab and see that the ajax request is getting sent?